# Count with binomial coefficients applied to linear algebra

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Show that for $n \geq 3$:

$\left(\begin{matrix}
N+n-1 \\
n
\end{matrix}\right)
+
\left(\begin{matrix}
N \\
n
\end{matrix}\right) \neq N^{n}$

I need this to show that $V^{\otimes n} \ncong S^{n}V \oplus \Lambda^{n}V$ for $n \geq 3$.

Comment: What have you tried? The LHS is $\leq 2^n N^n /n! +  N^n/ n! < N^n$ for $n>3$. You can prob get better bounds for $n=3$ just by approximating better.

Comment: I have been trying with an induction over n. This because expanding the coefficients I obtain: $\frac{N}{n!} ((N+n-1)\cdots(N+1)+(N-1)\cdots(N-n+1))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[N]=\{1,2,\dots,N\}$.

Each subset of size $n$ of $[N]$ determines a strictly increasing function from $[n]$ to $[N]$. Namely, writing such a subset as $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ with $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n$ are in sorted order, then the corresponding function is $i\mapsto x_i$.

On the other hand, $\binom{N+n-1}{n}$ enumerates multi-subsets of size $n$ of  $[N]$, and each of these subsets determines a weakly decreasing function from $[n]$ to $N$ in a similar fashion.

This proves that $\binom{N}{n}+\binom{N+n-1}{n}\le N^n$, and strict inequality is then proved by noting that there are functions from $[n]$ to $[N]$ which are neither strictly increasing nor weakly decreasing.